# Datagridview format column time update on multiple columns

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Studio 2010 in vb.net and retrieving the data from Access DB.

I need to format more than one column in a medium time format(00:00 PM). The code below works perfect for one column but I have another column in the same datagrid called TimeFinish that needs to be formatted in the same way.

Could someone please help me add a format to the TimeFinish column as well.
Cheers in advance.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

    If Me.DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "TimeStart" Then
        e.Value = String.Format("{0:t}", e.Value)
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, _ 
                                         ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _ 
                                         Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting 

    If Me.DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "TimeStart" Then 
        e.Value = String.Format("{0:t}", e.Value) 
    End If

    If Me.DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "TimeFinish" Then 
        e.Value = String.Format("{0:t}", e.Value) 
    End If

End Sub
```

If you're going to have a lot of different Ifs, you should rather use a Select Case:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, _ 
                                         ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _ 
                                         Handles 

    Select Case Me.DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
        Case "TimeStart"
            e.Value = String.Format("{0:t}", e.Value)

        Case "TimeFinish"
            e.Value = String.Format("{0:t}", e.Value)

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do i place the code. It doesn't work like this. I am a newbie too sorry.Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _
Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
        If Me.DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "TimeStart" Then
            e.Value = String.Format("{0:t}", e.Value) If Me.DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "TimeFinish" Then 
    e.Value = String.Format("{0:t}", e.Value) 
        End If

    End Sub

Comment: @Jason, I've edited my answer. Replace your code with the code in my answer. Everyone was a newbie once :)

Comment: Cheers Daniel, Is the code you supplied to display 2 columns. The column (TimeStart) & (TimeFinish) need to be formatted. The code you gave only shows a change on TimeFinish not both of these columns. The issue is i can format 1 column but i am confused about adding another column to this format sub.

Comment: @Jason, I've also added code for a Select Case... This is probably a better way to do the code above.

Comment: Thanks Heaps Daniel. I owe you a beer mate.